# WebElement becomes null during runtime

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-java

When I run this below code, i am getting null pointer exception on below part,
 I am running this with help of Cucumber and testng. why WebElement we becomes reset to null when i run all these steps in one go, eventhough i stored as `we=dr.findElement(By.id("email"));`

```
@When("^I get value from textbox using gettext$")
    public void i_get_value_from_textbox_using_gettext() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        System.out.println(we.toString());
        System.out.println("Getting value from text "+we.getText());
      //tbHelp.tbGetText(By.id("email"));
    }
```

Why WebElement we becomes null during runtime?
below is the complete code,

```
public class FbWebElementsStepDefn 
{

private WebDriver dr;
private BrowserHelper browserHelp;
private WebElement we;
private List<WebElement> totWes;
private TextBoxHelper tbHelp;

@Given("^Launching Chrome Browser and navigating to \"([^\"]*)\" to test$")
public void launching_Chrome_Browser_and_navigating_to_to_test(String url) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\\\seleniumJar\\\\chromedriver.exe");
    dr=new ChromeDriver();
    dr.get(url);
    browserHelp=BrowserHelper.getInstance(dr);
    browserHelp.BrowserMaximize();
    tbHelp=TextBoxHelper.getInstance(dr);

}

@Given("^I provide unique locator for webelement$")
public void i_provide_unique_locator_for_webelement() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    we=dr.findElement(By.id("email"));


}

@Then("^I should get desired webelement$")
public void i_should_get_desired_webelement() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
   System.out.println(we.toString());
}

@Then("^I close Browser$")
public void i_close_Browser() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    if(dr!=null)
    {
        dr.quit();
    }
}
@When("^I give non unique locator$")
public void i_give_non_unique_locator() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    totWes= dr.findElements(By.tagName("input"));

}

@Then("^I should get list of elements$")
public void i_should_get_list_of_elements() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    System.out.println("Total Elements "+totWes.size());
}
@When("^I enter value \"([^\"]*)\" in text box using sendkeys$")
public void i_enter_value_in_text_box_using_sendkeys(String value) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    //we=dr.findElement(By.id("email"));
    //we.sendKeys(value);
    tbHelp.tbEnterText(By.id("email"), value);
}

@When("^I get value from textbox using gettext$")
public void i_get_value_from_textbox_using_gettext() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    System.out.println(we.toString());
    System.out.println("Getting value from text "+we.getText());
  //tbHelp.tbGetText(By.id("email"));
}

@Then("^I clear textbox$")
public void i_clear_textbox() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    //we.clear();
    tbHelp.tbClearText(By.id("email"));


}
```

}

Comment: can you post the errors displayed on console after failure?
also replace these 3 lines browserHelp=BrowserHelper.getInstance(dr);
    browserHelp.BrowserMaximize();
    tbHelp=TextBoxHelper.getInstance(dr);
for these 2 lines driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver is your dr

Answer (score 0):

You can declare we as static field.

```
private static WebElement we;
```

But in my opinion it's a bad idea to create a cucumber step for providing elements. 
Try to read about Page Object Model which makes your automation experience much better!